How can I make parameters of CGAffineTransform get updated automaticlly in Shape while keeping all of path in visable view in SwiftUI?
I have a Rect view which comes from a shape. For the final touch, I need to use CGAffineTransform when adding my custom path. When I use CGAffineTransform, the parameters a and tx need to be calculated and updated inside the shape to keep the entire final path visible. Currently, I don't know the exact method to have a and tx update themselves while I am changing the view size. I have to adjust them manually using a slider, which is not part of the app or program—it's just a debugging tool. As you can see in the video, by changing the values of a and tx, I can keep the entire path within the frame, but the user needs this to happen automatically. So, how can I make a and tx update automatically while keeping the entire path in the frame?
Part 1:

Part 2:

code:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var a: Double = 0.8
    @State private var b: Double = 0
    @State private var c: Double = -0.17
    @State private var d: Double = 1
    @State private var tx: Double = 100
    @State private var ty: Double = 0

    var body: some View {
        
        FinalShape(a: a, b: b, c: c, d: d, tx: tx, ty: ty)
            .strokeBorder(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            .background(Color.purple)
            .cornerRadius(5.0)
            .padding()

        VStack {

            HStack {
                Text("a:")
                Slider(value: $a, in: -1...1)
            }
            
            HStack {
                Text("b:")
                Slider(value: $b, in: -1...1)
            }
            
            HStack {
                Text("c:")
                Slider(value: $c, in: -1...1)
            }
            
            HStack {
                Text("d:")
                Slider(value: $d, in: -1...1)
            }
            
            HStack {
                Text("tx:")
                Slider(value: $tx, in: -200...200)
            }
            
            HStack {
                Text("ty:")
                Slider(value: $ty, in: -200...200)
            }
 
        }
        .padding()

        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("a:" + String(describing: a))
                Text("b:" + String(describing: b))
                Text("c:" + String(describing: c))
                Text("d:" + String(describing: d))
                Text("tx:" + String(describing: tx))
                Text("ty:" + String(describing: ty))
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()

    }
}


struct FinalShape: InsettableShape {

    var a: Double
    var b: Double
    var c: Double
    var d: Double
    var tx: Double
    var ty: Double
    
    var insetAmount: CGFloat = CGFloat.zero

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return Path { path in

            let transform = CGAffineTransform(a: a, b: b, c: c, d: d, tx: tx, ty: ty)

            path.addPath(RecShape(insetAmount: insetAmount).path(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY), size: rect.size)), transform: transform)

        }
    }
    
    func inset(by amount: CGFloat) -> some InsettableShape {
        var myShape: Self = self
        myShape.insetAmount += amount
        return myShape
    }
}


struct RecShape: InsettableShape {
    var insetAmount: CGFloat = CGFloat.zero
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return Path { path in
            path.addRect(CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + insetAmount, y: rect.minY + insetAmount), size: CGSize(width: rect.width - 2*insetAmount, height: rect.height - 2*insetAmount)))
        }
    }
    func inset(by amount: CGFloat) -> some InsettableShape {
        var myShape: Self = self
        myShape.insetAmount += amount
        return myShape
    }
}


Is the only other variable the angle of slope, in other words, the factor c in the transformation? If so, why not just create a parallelogram Shape that uses all the space available without involving transformations?

That is right, the path of app is so complicated, this in question was a test and example

I assume that b, c, d, ty are all fixed.
Recall the equation that describes how a point will be transformed by an affine transform.
x' = ax + cy + tx
y' = bx + dy + ty

Based on your gifs, you seem to want the rectangle's minX and maxX to not change after applying the transformation. We can set up two equations and find the two unknowns a and tx. Here I have considered the two points (minX, maxY) and (maxX, minY).
minX = a * minX + c * maxY + tx
maxX = a * maxX + c * minY + tx

After solving these, you can write:
func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    let insettedRect = rect.insetBy(dx: insetAmount, dy: insetAmount)

    if insettedRect.minX - insettedRect.maxX == 0 {
        // in this case, the rect has no width, and the equation has no solution
        // - you should decide what you want to return 
        return Path()
    }
    
    // I just used the path from a Rectangle() here, but you can use any path you like
    let path = Rectangle().path(in: insettedRect)
    
    let numerator = (insettedRect.minX - c * insettedRect.maxY - insettedRect.maxX - c * insettedRect.minY)
    let a = numerator / (insettedRect.minX - insettedRect.maxX)
    let tx = insettedRect.maxX - a * insettedRect.maxX + c * insettedRect.minY
    return path.applying(CGAffineTransform(a, b, c, d, tx, ty))
}

What "inset" means for this shape is questionable. Here I just insetted the given rect, but I suggest not making this insettable at all.
Example usage:
FinalShape(b: 0, c: -0.17, d: 1, ty: 0)
            .strokeBorder(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            .background(Color.purple)
            .padding()

Note that it is still possible to pass in values of d and ty such that the shape exceeds the rectangle vertically. No values of a and tx can help you with that, because a and tx controls the transformation in the horizontal axis.

Thanks for help, where was this "x' = ax + cy + tx"? Any link, if I know this may I could solve the issue, be the way I tried to report back the a and tx to ContentView for showing the values, but I could not find any way rather than notification which is overkill for this, I tried in my answer this "var a: (CGFloat) -> ()" but there is error of "Stored property 'a' of 'Sendable'-conforming struct 'FinalShape' has non-sendable type '(CGFloat) -> ()'" can we report a snd tx to view back for showing numbers?

@swiftPunk The equations are stated in the documentation for CGAffineTransform.

@swiftPunk If you want to report back a and tx, Shape is not appropriate. I would write a View with @Bindings for a and tx. Then in that view, you might use GeometryReader to read the available size and create a CGRect for drawing the shape.

@swiftPunk If displaying a and tx is just for debugging purposes, you can do something "dirty" like putting @Bindings directly inside FinalShape, and set them in path(in:). However, you'd need to wrap them in a Task (or DispatchQueue.main.async), like Task { self.a = a; self.tx = tx }. Because path(in:) is called during a view update, and updating @State during a view update is undefined behaviour.

Or using your way of making Path via a func, then that would be more easier to use an inout or  '(CGFloat) -> ()'

Here is full code with accepted answer:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var a: CGFloat = 0.8
    @State private var b: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var c: CGFloat = -0.17
    @State private var d: CGFloat = 1
    @State private var tx: CGFloat = 100
    @State private var ty: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        
        FinalShape(b: b, c: c, d: d, ty: ty)
            .strokeBorder(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            .background(Color.purple)
            .cornerRadius(5.0)

        VStack {
            
            HStack {
                Text("b:")
                Slider(value: $b, in: -1...1)
            }
            
            HStack {
                Text("c:")
                Slider(value: $c, in: -1...1)
            }
            
            HStack {
                Text("d:")
                Slider(value: $d, in: -1...1)
            }

            HStack {
                Text("ty:")
                Slider(value: $ty, in: -200...200)
            }
 
        }
        .padding()
        

        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("a:" + String(describing: a))
                Text("b:" + String(describing: b))
                Text("c:" + String(describing: c))
                Text("d:" + String(describing: d))
                Text("tx:" + String(describing: tx))
                Text("ty:" + String(describing: ty))
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()

    }
}


struct RectangleShape: InsettableShape {
    var insetAmount: CGFloat = CGFloat.zero
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return Path { path in
            path.addRect(CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + insetAmount, y: rect.minY + insetAmount), size: CGSize(width: rect.width - 2*insetAmount, height: rect.height - 2*insetAmount)))
        }
    }
    func inset(by amount: CGFloat) -> some InsettableShape {
        var myShape: Self = self
        myShape.insetAmount += amount
        return myShape
    }
}


struct FinalShape: InsettableShape {

    var b: CGFloat
    var c: CGFloat
    var d: CGFloat
    var ty: CGFloat

    var insetAmount: CGFloat = CGFloat.zero

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return Path { path in

            let insettedRect = rect.insetBy(dx: insetAmount, dy: insetAmount)

            if ((insettedRect.minX - insettedRect.maxX) != .zero) {
                
                let numerator = (insettedRect.minX - c * insettedRect.maxY - insettedRect.maxX - c * insettedRect.minY)
                let a = numerator / (insettedRect.minX - insettedRect.maxX)
                let tx = insettedRect.maxX - a * insettedRect.maxX + c * insettedRect.minY

                let transform = CGAffineTransform(a: a, b: b, c: c, d: d, tx: tx, ty: ty)
                path.addPath(RectangleShape(insetAmount: insetAmount).path(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY), size: rect.size)), transform: transform)

            }
            else {
                // in this case, the rect has no width, and the equation has no solution
                print("The rect has no width!")
            }

        }
    }
    
    func inset(by amount: CGFloat) -> some InsettableShape {
        var myShape: Self = self
        myShape.insetAmount += amount
        return myShape
    }
}

